# Excel 2010 - Merge multiple connections into single worksheet

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, csv

I have an Excel workbook containing several worksheets.  Each worksheet has an external connection to a unique .csv file that is updated several times a day from different PCs.  This is done so that whenever the Excel workbook is opened, it will show the latest contents of all of the .csv files (as opposed to directly opening the .csv with write access; preventing any other machine from writing to it).  This allows multiple people to view the data being updated live with no issues.

I want to take all of the worksheets and compile them into a single worksheet.  The data has the same headers for each .csv connection.  I've tried calling multiple connections into one worksheet, but data gets staggered into completely different columns. For example, connection_1 to file1.csv is in rows A-C, connection_2 to file2.csv is in rows E-G, etc. (Not exact but it represents the issue.) I want everything to show the most recent data, but from all connections in rows A-C only.  (A.K.A. each row from the .csv files should merely append into one worksheet. Whenever the worksheet opens, it needs to have all of the most recent changes, as if the data was already in one big .csv file.)

Hopefully my description makes sense.  Does anyone know if this is possible without any add-ons/tools? I've seen some VB script that pulls several workbooks into one worksheet, but not multiple worksheet external references into one.

Comment: So you already have several data sources connect to one workbook? Or you need to accomplish that? And then you want each csv to be combines into a single worksheet?

Comment: Yes. The data sources are already connected to the workbook.  I want each connection to append the data it has all in the same worksheet.

Comment: Does each source have its own spreadsheet?

Comment: Each data source is a separate .csv file, so yes. They are technically different spreadsheets.